# Show SelectedValues Text Name

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is my table

```
ID   TestCaseName
 1   TestCycle1
 2   TestCycle2
 3   TestCycle3
```

Here I want to select the `ID` and while inserting in DB I want to show the `TEXT` i.e `TestCycle1`, I am trying this code.

1. I have tried the below mentioned code and in this I am getting the `ID` which I am storing in a property and while inserting in DB I want the `ID`'s `Text` to be inserted.

   ```
   private int TestCaseCycle;
   public int TestCaseCycle_Value
   {
       get { return TestCaseCycle; }
       set { TestCaseCycle = value; }
   }

   DefectManagement.TestCaseCycle_Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlTestCycle.SelectedValue);
   ```
2. Now while inserting in DB I want the `TEXT` of that `ID`, How can I insert selected index text in DB

Comment: Is it winform/web?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `SelectedText` property of the `DropDownList`. You could try something like below. Add a read only property to filter the `DropDownList` and then you could use that property to save into the DB.

```
private int TestCaseCycle;
public int TestCaseCycle_Value
{
    get { return TestCaseCycle; }
    set { TestCaseCycle = value; }
}

public string TestCaseCycle_Text // just a read only property
{
    get 
    {
        ddlTestCycle.Items.FindByValue(TestCaseCycle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

selected value is web forms:

you want the `ddlTestCycle.SelectedItem.Text`